# Why AND after a SET is not a syntax error in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I was surprised that this is not a syntax error:

```
UPDATE mytable  
SET deleted = 1 
AND name  = 'Cindy'
```

It doesn't affect the result of the command, is there any use of adding an `AND` after a `SET`? Or mysqsl will just ignore it?

Comment: you should use `set deleted = 1, name = 'cindy'`

Comment: It will evaluate to a boolean expression. `1 AND name  = 'Cindy'` which is `true AND name  = 'Cindy'` which is `name  = 'Cindy'`

Comment: This is similar to confusion about syntax `SELECT DISTINCT(column1),column2`... This is illusion...

Comment: Just of note, but delete is an Integer and it would fail if you did SET delete = '1' because that would be a VARCHAR .. I know this isn't the case at all here, but want to point this out, as quite a few times datatype issues like that are the cause, but in this case it was an order of operations but several good answers.

Comment: @easleyfixed not necessarily. Databases have incredible ways to convert data types. I am nearly confident that independently of the type `deleted` is, if you supply any digit, true/false or digit as string, it will convert. Unless the digit is too large for a numeric type.

Comment: I mean it depends alot on your DB but yeah,  this applies maybe even more on the front end code as it will not do that unless you test for the data types so i knows what they are instead of what they are expected to be.  And yeah INT only goes up so high, but its up there.  The one that scares me is UNIXTIMESTAMP going RIP in like 2038 .. its going to be like Y2K over again, as I suspect many applications like using the system, granted a replacement will be out by then, but I digress, thanks for the input.

Comment: There's an old bug for this, too. https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=19398

Comment: @ValerieParham-Thompson *There's an old bug for this, too.* The fact that this situations was reported on bugs.mysql.com does not mean that it is a bug.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, @Akina. I should have used the complete term "bug report."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement takes into account the [operators precedence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/operator-precedence.html). And the query acts as

```sql
UPDATE mytable  
SET deleted = (1 AND (name  = 'Cindy'))
```

I.e. firstly the condition `name  = 'Cindy'` is tested producing TRUE (1), FALSE (0) or NULL.

Then the expression `1 AND {result}` is evaluated.

And finally the result of this expression evaluation is assigned into `deleted` column.

[DEMO fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/RYA4voKK)

If you receive the same result like for

```sql
UPDATE mytable  
SET deleted = 1
```

then `name` column value is equal to `'Cindy'` using current collation.

Answer (score 6):

Because the expression:

```
1 AND name  = 'Cindy'
```

is a Boolean expression that evaluates to `0` for `False` or `1` for `True`
and the value of this expression will be assigned to the column `deleted`,  like:

```
SET deleted = (1 AND (name = 'Cindy'))
```

Comment: so it will *not* ignore it; the update will set deleted to 1 when the name is Cindy and 0 for all other rows.

Comment: @ysth yes, since 1 means TRUE, the result will be the value of `name = 'Cindy'`